# Mac Terminal Compiling Errors

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++

Note: I do have xcode installed as well as its command line tools.

> gcd.cpp:6:20: fatal error: `iostream`: No such file or directory

Is the error I get in terminal when running:

> g++ gcd.cpp -o gcd -g -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -fmessage-length=0

I have no idea how to fix this issue. Any one know how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int gcdRecur(int a, int b) {
    if(b == 0)
        return a;
    else    
        return gcdRecur(b, a % b);
} 

int gcdIter(int a, int b) {
    int z;
        while(b != 0) {
            z = b;
            b = a%b;
            a = z;
        }
        return a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3){
        printf("Usage: %s <integer m> <integer n>", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    string m_str = (string) argv[1];
    string n_str = (string) argv[2];
    istringstream iss;
    int m = 0, n = 0;
    iss.str(m_str);
    // Check if the first argument is an integer
    // by giving the istringstream 0
    if(!(iss >> m)){
        cerr << "Error: The first argument is not a valid integer." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    iss.clear();
    iss.str(n_str);
    if(!(iss >> n)){
        cerr << "Error: The second argument is not a valid integer." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    int iter = gcdIter(m, n);
    int recur = gcdRecur(m, n);
    printf("Iterative: gcd(%d, %d) = %d\nRecursive: gcd(%d, %d) = %d\n", m, n, iter, m, n, recur);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Running the command:

> g++ -H gcd.cpp -o gcd -g -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -fmessage-length=0

I now get this output(it will do the same error for sstream if I switch the order of it and iostream):

```
. /usr/include/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
... /usr/include/sys/_symbol_aliasing.h
... /usr/include/sys/_posix_availability.h
.. /usr/include/Availability.h
... /usr/include/AvailabilityInternal.h
.. /usr/include/_types.h
... /usr/include/sys/_types.h
.... /usr/include/machine/_types.h
..... /usr/include/i386/_types.h
.... /usr/include/sys/_pthread/_pthread_types.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_va_list.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_size_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_null.h
.. /usr/include/sys/stdio.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_off_t.h
.. /usr/include/sys/_types/_ssize_t.h
```

Comment: Look for predefined flags in XCode. You may need to specify the path(s) of your standard library implementation.

Comment: Run again with the -H flag. i.e. g++ -H test.cpp -o gcd -g -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -fmessage-length=0 . This will display the preprocessors attempts at loading header files. That might give an indication of what is going on. On my macbook iostream is found here . /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream

Comment: Are you using XCode's g++ (which is actually clang) or have you installed your own?

Comment: I have brew installed gcc-5 and created the symlinks.

Comment: Not sure but I think brew gcc-5 doesn't install headers, just the compiler and links to OSX headers, so you need to install xode and its tools because headers are not provided by default under osx.

Comment: I had xcode installed before brew installing gcc-5. Also have the command line tools installed.

Comment: Well, I've compiled and run your program in my environment (Mac OSX/clang) and it runs ok.  That must be a compiler trouble, as it is complainting about `iostream` not found.  As the error signals line 6 and nothing is found there, I suppose you have touched the source before sending.  Any way, a recommendation is never mix `stdio.h` and `iostream` calls in a source, as undefined behaviour can occur (mainly calling to `fflush(stdout);` when you are printing using `cout`'s `<<` operator.  You have to use the flushing buffer method in `cout` for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to make sure that you have the Xcode command line tools installed.  From the terminal run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

More info: http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/

Whenever I get stuck trying to figure out what the compiler did in Xcode, I always go to see what the command Xcode used was.  In your project go to the Report navigator (should be on the left hand side, far right tab):

[image]

Then find the line for the file that you are interested in seeing further:

[image]

Click on the little stack of pancakes on the far right to expand:

[image]

Comment: Hmm Okay I got to that menu, but I don't know what I am looking at well enough to see why its working in Xcode and not terminal.